# Laravel package ServiceProvider not found

Tags: php, laravel, package, packagist

I have created a PHP package for laravel named zoho.

```
namespace rahulreghunath\zoho;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider as IlluminateServiceProvider;

    class ServiceProvider extends IlluminateServiceProvider
    {
        /**
         * Bootstrap the application services.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function boot()
        {
            $this->publishes([
                __DIR__.'/../config/zoho.php' => config_path('zoho.php'),
            ]);

        }

        /**
         * Register the application services.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function register()
        {

        }
    }
```

and composer file is

```
{
    "name": "rahulreghunath/zoho",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
    },
    "description": "PHP form validation plugin ",
    "homepage": "https://github.com/rahulreghunath/zoho-crm",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Rahul Reghunath",
            "email": "reghunath11@gmail.com",
            "role": "developer"
        }
    ]
}
```

package is working fine when I created which is not in vendor folder but when I
submitted to Packagist and install using composer and it shows the error

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
  Class 'rahulreghunath\zoho\ServiceProvider' not found
```

When running vendot:publish command
even if provider `rahulreghunath\Zoho\ServiceProvider::class,`
is added to config/app.php

is that any error in autoloading in composer file
anyway thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer myself

changed the composer.json to

```
{
    "name": "rahulreghunath/zoho",
    "description": "Zoho CRM integration for PHP-Laravel",
    "license": "MIT",
    "keywords": ["laravel", "zoho"],
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Rahul Reghunath",
            "email": "reghunath11@gmail.com",
            "role": "developer"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9"
    },

    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Rahulreghunath\\Zoho\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

and service provider to

```
Rahulreghunath\Zoho\ServiceProvider::class,
```